# How to see logs when running app in iOS simulator directly?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I want to run an app in iOS simulator directly and see the log emitted from NSLog (rather than running the app from Xcode). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the runtime version, you can use one of:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted syslog -w
xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream
tail -F "$(xcrun simctl getenv booted SIMULATOR_LOG_ROOT)/system.log"
```

If you're on macOS Sierra, you can also select the simulated device from within Console.app to see the logs.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a OSX tool for this?

Comment: I don't understand your followup question.  Open up Terminal.app and run those commands.

Comment: I mean - is there a GUI tool like Console app that can do this instead of terminal.

Comment: Yeah, just use Console and either. rowse to the file (older runtimes) or select the simulated device (newer runtimes).

Comment: Any way to see the output of `print` statements in Swift?